# PHP run simultaneously remote script(bash) over ssh

Tags: php, ssh

I want to be able to run simutaneously multiple remote (bash) script overs ssh on a remote servers with php.

Get the result of the sripts back ( exit code ) and the stdout of the scripts.

I was thinking of sharing ssh keys with the master(where the php is located) with the slave (where the script is executed) and use the buit-in ssh command in php to run the script over ssh and retrieve the output and exit code.

```
$stream = ssh2_exec($conn, 'php -v');
stream_set_blocking($stream, true);
$stream_out = ssh2_fetch_stream($stream, SSH2_STREAM_STDIO);
echo stream_get_contents($stream_out);
```

But i didn't find a solutions to run multiple remote script over ssh.
Because i want to show the status (starting,terminated) of my mutiple instance of executed script when the user start the function to execute them in php and show him the current status ( a little bit like Jenkins).

Comment: I'm not totally sure what you mean. But can't you achieve this by using threads in PHP?

Comment: sorry my english is not good. So i want to execute multiple remote ssh script, show an html page of all the current executing script ant the current status

Comment: Yes. So you want to execute multiple remote ssh scripts at the same time. You can use threads for this. http://php.net/manual/en/class.thread.php

Comment: yes but how to retrieve the command output and exit code from the remote server ?